# Can we test angular 2 application without mocking any services?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

Currently I'm mocking my services to test my angular 2 application using Jasmine-Karma. I was just wondering if it is possible to test a component as whole(Model,View,Controller) without mocking any services/models. If the answer is no, then why is mocking essential for testing a component? I went through many resources but couldn't find any examples that performed testing without mocking any services.

Comment: Because it's a bad practice.

Comment: Can you please explain in a concrete example why this is a problem? If your component declares that it depends on services (constructor parameters), why do you think testing them without these services makes even sense? You can declare the constructor parameters as optional using the `@Optional()` annotation to prevent getting exceptions when providers are missing.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer For instance, I have a login component and login model verifies if the account exist in the database and based on the result it either accepts or rejects the request. By mocking we actually stop the application from accessing real back-end and create a hard coded method which checks for same but without hitting the back end. Now, what if the actual model has an error in the code and actually looks for different account in the back end? This wouldn't get noticed in the test, right? Correct me if i'm wrong...

Comment: I see. I misinterpreted your question. You ask why mocks are provided instead of the real thing. I thought you don't want to provide anything.
It's bad practice as Swoox already mentioned. You should write other tests to test the model instead. The main advantage of DI is that you easily **can** mock almost everything, so that one test tests a single thing, not (accidentally) ~1/3 ;-) of your application. If you don't use mocks to break up dependencies, you're writing integration tests, not unit tests. You can do that of course, but put them at least in a different directory

Comment: ... and don't call them unit tests.